# MIME type error calling js files in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor, mime-types

I've added CKEditor javascript library to my application. When calling ckeditor.js script i'm getting an nosniff mime type error.
This is error displayed in the developer console:
"Did not load script at 'http://localhost:4200/ckeditor/ckeditor.js' because non script MIME types are not allowed when 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' is given."
How can i overcome this error?

Comment: not clear how did you added the CKeditor via index.html or via npm ?

Comment: I've added it via npm (sudo npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) and calling the js like this in index.html: ./node_modules/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/build/ckeditor.js

Comment: My reference url: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic